# error in opening website from ipv6 address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, ipv6, apache2.2

I have installed **apache2** in my **ubunntu 12.10** system with **inet addr 172.16.17.235** and **inet6 addr fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4/64** in LAN. 
Now when i want to open default website (index.html) located in /var/www/ , i simply write 
 **http://localhost** or 
 **http://127.0.0.1** or 
 **http://172.16.17.235** in my web browser(firefox 17.0) and it opens that **index.html** page 
but when i want to access this **index.html** with the help of **ipv6 addressing** as below :
**http://[::1]**  or
**http://[fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4]**

following error is shown by browser :
**Unable to connect Firefox** 
can't establish a connection to the server at [::1]  or
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at [fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4].

Can any one tell me what configuration am i missing in my system or what i am doing wrong.

**BTW** when i ping to my localhost as :
ping6 ::1 or ping6  -I eth0 fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4 
ping reply is coming fine as :
 **64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms** 
 or 
**64 bytes from fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an IPv6 address from the `fe80::` range, you must specify over which network adapter it should go. (Technically, you must provide the Zone ID which correlates with the network adapter used).

On ping, you do that with `-l eth0`. In Firefox, you can do that with `http://[fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%x]` where `x` is a positive number you must find out.

---

EDIT: If you absolutely don't find out what is going on, you could try this:

```
python -c 'import sys,socket; print socket.getaddrinfo(sys.argv[1], (sys.argv[2:]+[0])[0], 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)' fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%eth0
```

and have a look to the result. On my system, it looks like

```
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%eth0', 0, 0, 3))]
```

where the last number, the `3`, is the real Zone ID.

If this gives you a result, your name resolution works fine, if not, it is broken.

The next step could be to try to create a HTTP connection:

```
python -c 'import sys,socket; c=socket.create_connection((sys.argv[1], 80)); c.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n"); print c.recv(100000).split("\r\n\r\n",1)[0]' fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%eth0
```

If that works, the problem is your browser, if not, you cannot reach the server due to whatever reason. (Does your web server daemon bind to IPv6?)

Comment: i have tried writing http://[fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%0] and http://[fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%64] but both are opening the google result with above query...here 0 is the no of my Ethernet adapter (eth0) and i tried 64 because on writing ifconfig my system showing inet6 addr as fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4/64....still not working.....

Comment: @r.bhardwaj 64 is the subnet address. Under Linux you can as well use `eth0`, otherwise you could try 1, 2 etc.

Comment: none of %1,%2,%3..etc is working. in each case browser searches it as a google query .... any other suggestion ?

Comment: no %eth0 also not working..but whet i enter [::1] with no proxy in browser it is working but again  [fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4] or [fe80::a05b:25ff:fef0:68a4%x] not working ...

Comment: @r.bhardwaj That is because `::1` is unambiguous. Being link-local, `fe80::` are per se ambiguous so their zone must be specified as well. Strange that it doesn't work...

Comment: i think my proxy server does not have support for ipv6 thats why it is unable to open the address but as my local host has support have support for both ipv4 and ipv6, browser is opening [::1] = ip6-localhost with no proxy....and i don;t think we need to use %x in browser as whenever i m doing it browser searches it as search engine query ..

Comment: glglgl is technically right, to use a link local IPv6 address, you need to specify a zone id with it, most commonly the interface name. It already worked with FF quite some time ago, but has been reported broken end 2011 (see [issue #700999](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700999)). Besides FF, I tested chrome and konqueror, none of them does the job. I successfully issued a GET request to a link local address using telnet, which worked, so this is really lack of browser support at the moment.